# How perform DOM Manipulation in JS with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I'm trying to perform DOM manipulation in JS. I've been learning JS and HTML/CSS on scrimba (I'm at a beginner level), and I am trying to do exactly what I was taught. However, it seems like I can not perform DOM manipulation outside of the Scrimba environment. I am currently running VSCode with Node.js. Its hard for me to believe that there isn't a simple solution to this problem.

The code I am using is the follow:

```
let test = document.getElementById('result');

function num7(){
    test.textContent = "HWLLO"
}
```

I have tested the num7 function as it connects to a button (I'm trying to build a calculator), and I know that it works.

Any help will be hugely appreciate and ask questions if you have any.

Comment: Node has no DOM. You will need to load the JavaScript in to a HTML page and view it in a browser.

Comment: Node runs on the command line, not within a web page.  There *is no* `document` in the context of Node, because why would there be?  It sounds like what you really want is to write JavaScript code on a web page that would be viewed in a browser, not in Node.  (Though Node could be used to host a web server which *serves* that page to the browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Node doesnt factor in to this equation but I "think" this is what you are looking for.  If it is not correct let me know the HTML and I will  adjust.

```js
let test = document.getElementById('result');

function num7(){
    test.innerHTML = "HWLLO"
}

num7();
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: for future readers and searchers where seo picks up the title, this doesn't answer "How perform DOM Manipulation in JS with Node.js", the question title should be changed to suit the question or removed altogether since just fixing the OP's code is just adding one line to call the function is more of a typo, which can be voted on.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing is right!

But you need to understand the difference between running Javascript using `nodejs` vs running it in a `browser`. They're completely different though they're running both javascript.

Nodejs doesn't have the concept of DOM. What your code does is accessing a DOM and manipulate its content, and it's only applicable when you run your javascript using a browser.

Try create an HTML file and place your code there, and make sure to open using your browser.

Another thing to note is, your code must be structured like the below

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");

function num7() {
  result.textContent = 7;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="num7()">7</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

There other ways to make this dynamic like passing arguments to use as the value for the `textContent`

Comment: Thank you for this advice. At first, when I tried your code, it didn't work and gave me the same error message. I then looked at my html code and I realized that I had put the script in the head tag, so I moved in down to the first div, which basically contains all of the html for the calculator. After that I think it worked... Do you know why putting it in the head tag might have been causing this problem?

Comment: It’s because it runs your script and yet the DOM is not loaded to browser. But, when you create the script before the closing tag of the body, it assures that the DOM are already that time. You can still put the script in the head tag but you have to add some listener to make your code working if you want to try check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event